# Chat transcript thinks I pinned a message. I didn't

Tags: bug, chat

[image: Screenshot of message dropdown]

I'd starred [this message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19148234#19148234), but now the message dropdown is suggesting that I'd also pinned it.

In truth, not only is the message not pinned at all, but I'm not a room owner (*sniff*) so I couldn't make it so even if I wanted to (which I sorta do, come to think of it).

I've done some digging and it turns out that this is the case for all messages that I have starred, *but only in the transcript*, rather than the live view.

Comment: We should ban you for pretending to have owner powers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I consider not being a Lounge owner to be a privilege.

Comment: It is a privilege.  The Lounge should charge for immunity from ownership and spend the cash on beer at unconferences.

Comment: @MartinJames: Two unpints of undoom bar, please.