# Pinned message not appearing in chat sidebar

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

In the Python chat room, we have a [message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37997172#37997172) that we like to keep pinned, because it is a useful reference for new users that are unfamiliar with the markup system.

An RO pinned the message, and it stayed on the sidebar star list for a few days before falling off automatically, as expected. Another RO pinned it again, and the same thing happened. So far so good.

Here is the problem: I tried to pin the message a third time. The interface indicates that it was pinned successfully. But the message is not on the star list.

[image]

---

[image]

I've confirmed that this is not just a problem on my end. Other ROs are also unable to pin the message, and both ROs and ordinary users are unable to see the message in the star list.

Is this a bug? Or is it by design that a message can't be pinned arbitrarily many times? Is there a workaround?

Comment: If it’s by design: This is a `feature-request` for permanent pins.

Comment: I tested in another room with a message that was only pinned once and then expired: the problem exists there too. So the problem is probably not because there are too many pinholes in that poor message.

Comment: Just for some additional information: The API call for unpinning just returns `"ok"` without actually changing anything about the situation. Calling the pin API just returns `"You have already voted, but the voting has been cleared by a moderator"`.

Comment: @poke there's [a feature-request on overmeta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276671/keep-pinned-messages-pinned-without-14-days-limit-in-chat-rooms)

Comment: Why don't you add this link up in the room description instead?  (I don't know what the length limit is for the field, but the text that is currently there is not particularly useful anyway).

Comment: @wim not that this concerns this bug, but anyway I have a feeling that the post would be less visible in the room description. After all the room rules are there in the description, and most users don't bother reading that either.

Comment: On a side note: It already indicates pinning if you just star it. Might be something for another post. I am neither RO nor do I have any other privileges. If I star a message and open the shown menu it reads the same text despite it not being pinned.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 do you mean [this ancient bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272383/chat-transcript-thinks-i-pinned-a-message-i-didnt)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Indeed I do. I tried to look it up but could not find that one. Thanks :)